# Pandas between_time boolean

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a column that will assign true if row value falls between the times 09:00 and 17:00.

I can select those times easily enough using `between_time` but can't assign a new column a `True`, `False`.

```
df = df.between_time('9:00', '17:00', include_start=True, include_end=True)
```

This statement selects the appropriate rows, but I can't assign a True-False value to them.

I've been trying to use `np.where`.

```
df['day'] = np.where(df.between_time('9:00', '17:00', include_start=True, include_end=True),'True','False')
```

Except that `np.where` only works on boolean expressions.

I've used it like this:

```
df['day'] = np.where((df['dayTime'] < '09:00') & (df['dayTime'] > '17:00'),'True','False')
```

But only gotten `False returns`, because a value can't be greater than 17 and less than 9 at the same time.

I'm missing a relatively easy step and can't figure it out. Help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```
df.index.isin(df.between_time('9:00', '17:00', include_start=True, include_end=True).index)
```

Because the `between` method returns a dataframe, rather than a boolean array we can call `.index` on it as we could with any dataframe, this will return a series of times. We can then check wether or not our original time indices are in our time indices resulting from the `between` method.

This will give you a boolean array of values that are within your time frame. I can't think of another way to do this, but that doesn't mean there isn't one

Comment: This works great, thanks. could you explain the significance of the `.index` at the end of the between_time statement?

Comment: Added an edit, hopefully that clarifies what is going on a bit.