# mark rows with timestamp between times

Tags: pandas, timestamp

I need to mark rows in a time series where the timestamps fall between given time-of-day blocks; when I have eg

```
values = ([ 'motorway' ] * 5000) + ([ 'link' ] * 300) + ([ 'motorway' ] * 7000)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
  'timestamp': pd.date_range(start='2018-1-1', end='2018-1-2', freq='s').tolist()[:len(values)],
  'road_type': values,
})
df.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)
```

I need to add a column `rush` that marks rows where `timestamp` is between `06:00` and `09:00` or `15:30` and `19:00`. I've seen [between_time](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) but I don't know how to apply it here.

edit: based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35004241/pandas-between-time-boolean) I managed to put together

```
df['rush'] = df.index.isin(df.between_time('00:00:15', '00:00:20', include_start=True, include_end=True).index) | df.index.isin(df.between_time('00:00:54', '00:00:59', include_start=True, include_end=True).index)
```

but I wonder whether there isn't a more elegant way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One alternative using [`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html)

```
from datetime import time as t

values = ([ 'motorway' ] * 5000) + ([ 'link' ] * 300) + ([ 'motorway' ] * 7000)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
 'timestamp': pd.date_range(start='2018-1-1', end='2018-1-2',
                               freq='s').tolist()[:len(values)],
  'road_type': values,
})

time = df['timestamp'].dt.time

df['rush'] = (time.between(t(0,6,0), t(0,9,0)) | time.between(t(0,15,30),t(0,19,0))).values
```

Or slicing the `df` using `datetime.time`

```
df = df.set_index(df.timestamp.dt.time)

df['rush'] = df.index.isin(df[t(0,6,0):t(0,9,0)].index | df[t(0,15,30):t(0,19,0)].index)

df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```